# Autodesk DataVisualisation API error when adding viewableData

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Autodesk.Datavisualisation examples gives me error at:

```
        dataVizExtn.addViewables(viewableData);
```

It says that "addViewables" does not exist for type 'Extension'
I've declared dataVizExtn as

```
const dataVizExtn = await this.viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DataVisualization");
```

Using the latest forge viewer 7.9*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by type casting the extension like so:

```
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.DataVisualization').then((dataVizExtn: any) => {
    dataVizExtn.addViewables(viewableData);
});
```

Comment: I've managed to go past that error but it doesn't seem to be loading any sprites, although there's no error. Any way to load the sprites into the object tree or see if they area in the scene?